# Rails migrations after database reset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, migration, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

Hi I have a general migration problem:

When I create migrations like this:

```
class RenameColumn < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_column :users, :hotel_stars, :rating_stars
    rename_column :users, :restaurant_stars, :price_stars
  end
end
```

and change the code in the Model-,View- and Controller file accordingly(I dont create new Model etc.):

ie.

```
Model: attr_accessible :rating_stars, :price_stars
```

(instead of :hotel_stars, :restaurant_stars )

```
Controller: @rating = current_user.rating_stars
```

When I now run the migration (rake db:migrate) -> it works!
But after a rake db:drop, rake db:create, rake db:migrate it doesn't anymore!

What is wrong with this migration? How can you create migrations that are working WITH and WITHOUT resetting the database?

Thanks!!

Comment: Please give the exact error message.  I can't tell what the problem is from "it doesn't anymore!".  Thanks.

Comment: Rails version 3.1.2
I don't have one error message. Because I'm having problems with migrations all the time... The error message is different each time. The error with this migration was, that it changed the name of the columns, but the content in the columns disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that rake db:create does not rebuild your database from schema.rb.  For that you need to do rake db:setup instead of rake db:create.  In any case I would try rake db:reset instead of drop/create as I believe that will accomplish what you want to do in one step.

Type rake -T for a list of available tasks and what they do.

Also see here for more information on rails migrations:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever manually alter the state of your database and/or modify a migration after it was run? If so, you messed up the state of migrations.

You "could" alleviate this by adding a migration that gets your database where your new migration expects it to be, or you could fix the migration that was altered before.

Depending on how many other developers you have, I would go for the latter in this case.

Comment: Hi! I think I manipulated older migrations somehow... isn't it sufficient to do rake db:drop create and migrate? or does manipulating older migration files cause a lot more problems than that?